# Counting matrix elements that have "4" or "5" as a neighbor

Tags: c++, matrix, r, ffi

I have a matrix (500x500) of integers. For each entry, I need to look at its surrounding neighbours (so 8 elements) and determine what the integers are, and run a function on these integers.

Here what my function looks like right now (R code with the RCpp package).

```
fx2<- cppFunction('NumericMatrix getNeighbours(NumericMatrix x) {
            int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();

            //create a result matrix of probabilities
            NumericMatrix outProb(nrow, ncol);

            // some counters needed to calculate probability 
            int kc = 0; int kpre = 0; int ks = 0;

            // i and j loop through the elements one by one. 
            //  - ignore the boundary as I dont know how to handle it for now
            for (int i = 1; i < (nrow-1); i++) {
              for (int j = 1; j < (ncol-1); j++) {

                // go through the neighbours
                for(int k = -1; k <= 1; k++){
                  for(int l = -1; l <= 1; l++){

                    // check what values the neighbours are

                    // increment the kc
                    if(x(i + k, j + l) == 4){
                      kc++;
                    }

                    // increment the ks counter
                    if(x(i + k, j + l) == 5){
                      ks++;
                    }

                    // more if statements removed for readibility

                  }
                } //end of loop for neighbours

                // calculate a probability for the resulting matrix
                outProb(i, j) = functionof(kc, ks, kpre);                
              }              
            }
            return outProb;
            }')
```

I am looking to make this code faster/more efficient.

Example of result: Suppose the `functionof` just doubles the value of the counter.

```
> health
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    4    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

We see that `(2, 1)`, `(1, 2)` and `(2, 2)` have `4` as their neighbours. So the output would be

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    2    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Note that there are other elements in the matrix that have `4` as a neighbour. I've omitted that from the `result` matrix above.

I currently wrote the code in R but even after vectorizing/parallelizing it is still very slow. So now I've moved on to a C++ function that I can call using R's `RCpp` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you could write your code efficiently in base R:

```
offset <- function(x, v_offset = 0L, h_offset = 0L) {
   stopifnot(h_offset %in% -1:1, v_offset %in% -1:1)
   nr <- nrow(x)
   nc <- ncol(x)
   if (h_offset == +1L) x <- cbind(x[, -1], -99L)
   if (h_offset == -1L) x <- cbind(-99L, x[, -nc])
   if (v_offset == +1L) x <- rbind(x[-1, ], -99L)
   if (v_offset == -1L) x <- rbind(-99L, x[-nr, ])
   x
}

getNeighbours <- function(x, functionof) {
   v_offsets <- c(-1, -1, -1,  0,  0, +1, +1, +1)
   h_offsets <- c(-1,  0, +1, -1, +1, -1,  0, +1)
   neigh_x   <- Map(offset, list(x), v_offsets, h_offsets)
   kc   <- Reduce(`+`, Map(function(x) x == 4L, neigh_x))
   ks   <- Reduce(`+`, Map(function(x) x == 5L, neigh_x))
   kpre <- 0
   functionof(kc, ks, kpre)
}
```

It builds a list (`neigh_x`) of eight matrices in memory, one for each neighboring position. Instead of four loops, you are down to a single loop (8 iterations) wherever you see `Map` or `Reduce`, everything else uses vectorized operations.

Testing the code:

```
health <- matrix(1, 5, 5)
health[1, 1] <- 4
test_fun <- function(kc, ks, kpre) 2 * (kc + ks + kpre)

getNeighbours(health, functionof = test_fun)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    2    0    0    0
# [2,]    2    2    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: This is pretty neat! Could you help explain what is happening?

Comment: Maybe this will help understand. You probably know that `x == 4` returns a matrix showing you what cells in `x` have a value of `4`. Well, with the `offset` function I built, you can for example do `offset(x, h_offset = 1) == 4` to find what cells have a `4` to their right (horizontal offset of 1) . `neigh_x` is a list of eight matrices computing the shifted versions of `x`. `Map` then helps you loop over that list to return a list of eight boolean matrices where the neighboors are (eg.) equal to 4. The `Reduce(`+`, ...)` turns these 8 matrices into their sum. I bet you'll figure out the rest.

Comment: Ahh thanks, that makes sense! Two more quick questions: Is there a way to parallelize this code? I have a large cluster I am going to run this on. Second,  are there libraries in C++ that can help achieve this functional method. I'd like to compare the speeds.

Comment: parallelize: do you have one gigantic matrix or a gigantic number of matrices? If the former, the single (Map/Reduce) loop has only 8 iterations, so I don't see a huge need to parallelize if your matrix already holds in memory. If the latter, sure, you could search the internet. Equivalent c++ code: isn't what you did already sufficient? It is probably already faster than my R solution. R can't really compete with c++.

Comment: There is a slight modification I am trying to make but can't. I only want to run this "logic" of finding neighbours if the element in the matrix is 1 or 2. Is there a way to modify this somehow. I am failing to see where I can modify this

Comment: if i understand correctly, multiply `kc` and `ks` (or the final output) by `x %in% c(1, 2)`?

Comment: Don't forget to add your comments to your answer, they increase it's value.